# Can I copy the docker qcow2 file from an ubuntu server to my mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

I have an ubuntu server where I installed docker to run some containers. I want to move everything to my Mac so I don't depend on the ubuntu server. Will it work if I copy the qcow2 file from the server to my Mac?

Comment: how many images do you have on ubuntu which eventually like to move?

Comment: @Rao just one. It's a ~20GB postgres db.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it from your ubuntu machine in two ways dependening your need.

- **docker export**
- **docker save**

If you want the container's file system, then use `docker export`

```
$ docker export container_name > pg_container_db.tar
```

If you just want your image file system, use below command instead of `docker export`

```
$ docker save image_name > pg_container_db.tar
```

Any of the above two commands creates an archive on ubuntu machine. Later you can use it on mac.

Copy the above `pg_container_db.tar` file to mac & run below command

```
$ docker load < pg_container_db.tar
```

Once the above command is successful on you mac, you should be able to see by using `docker images` command.